# Wrapping the Twilio Node Client in a Meteor application using wrapAsync fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, twilio

I'm trying to wrap the Twilio Node client so I can access and use it from my Meteor application. I am using `npm-container` and added the twilio package to my `packages.json` file. I am then creating a Meteor method to call and trying to wrap the NPM package call to be able to send an SMS message.

```
  sendSMS: function() {
    var twilio = Meteor.npmRequire('twilio');
    var client = new twilio(Meteor.settings.TWILIO.SID, Meteor.settings.TWILIO.TOKEN);

    var options = {
      to: Meteor.settings.TWILIO.TO,
      from: Meteor.settings.TWILIO.FROM,
      body: 'word to your mother.'
    };

    var sms = Meteor.wrapAsync(client.sendMessage, client);

    return sms(options);
  }
```

But when I call `Meteor.call('sendSMS');` from my Meteor client, I get an internal server error...

```
I20150603-12:05:29.254(-4)? Exception while invoking method 'sendSMS' [object Object]
I20150603-12:05:29.254(-4)?     at Object.Future.wait (/Users/jeremyhodges/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
I20150603-12:05:29.254(-4)?     at packages/meteor/helpers.js:119:1
I20150603-12:05:29.254(-4)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.sendSMS (app/server/index.js:229:12)
I20150603-12:05:29.254(-4)?     at [object Object].methodMap.(anonymous function) (packages/meteorhacks:kadira/lib/hijack/wrap_session.js:160:1)
I20150603-12:05:29.254(-4)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1617:1)
I20150603-12:05:29.255(-4)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648:1
I20150603-12:05:29.255(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20150603-12:05:29.255(-4)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:647:1
I20150603-12:05:29.255(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20150603-12:05:29.255(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.method (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:646:1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio is throwing an error. You will have to investigate to debug further:

```
try {
    var sms = Meteor.wrapAsync(client.sendMessage, client);

    return sms(options);
}catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message)
}
```

`e.message` should contain more information about the issue. This is also the same information given by `client.sendMessage`'s first parameter in its callback (typically the error)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Async.wrap](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm#asyncwrapfunction).

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

  var twilio = Meteor.npmRequire('twilio');
  var client = twilio(Meteor.settings.TWILIO.SID, Meteor.settings.TWILIO.TOKEN);
  var wrappedClient = Async.wrap(client, ['sendMessage']);

  Meteor.methods({

    sendSMS: function(){

      var options = {
        to: Meteor.settings.TWILIO.TO,
        from: Meteor.settings.TWILIO.FROM,
        body: 'word to your mother.'
      }

      return wrappedClient.sendMessage(options);

    }

  })

}
```